# does there exist a vector space of every dimension?

Tags: linear-algebra

its trivial for countable dimension but I want to show given any random set with a random cardinality there exists a vector space of dimension equal to the cardinality of the set.

I think I have a proof when I assume the continuum hypothesis but I want to do it without assuming it.
you may of course assume axiom of choice.

Comment: If you would provide your proof that *does* assume the continuum hypothesis, that would be great. :)

Comment: If you just want a vector space with no additional structure, you can take the free vector space generated by your set (of any cardinality). This essentially means declaring your set as a formal Hamel basis.